# ASPx Dev Express File Upload Control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, devexpress

I want to be able to upload a file onto my server.

I know my code works, I cannot figure out what is going on with the path name though, and how to set it to the websites directory.

Here is my c#

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
                string uploadFolder = "~/files/";
                string fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName;

                e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(uploadFolder + fileName);
                e.CallbackData = fileName;
        }
```

This is the error message I get when trying to upload the file

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\~\files\project_questionnaire.doc'.
```

I have tried everything for the uploadFolder... "../files" "files/" "/files/" etc..

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
                string uploadFolder = Server.MapPath("~/files/");
                string fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName;

                e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(uploadFolder + fileName);
                e.CallbackData = fileName;
        }
```

See [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths) for a good guide.

Comment: Excellent and concise example for the use of Server.MapPath (+1)